# Spring DBUnit : Limiting spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl execution

Tags: spring, jpa, dbunit

I have an abstract class that I extend when creating tests for our annotation config based Spring application. I am using an embedded H2 database and as such have my spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl.auto=create-drop. In the class below you can see that I create an entityManager from the EntityManagerFactory in the @Before method of the below class. This means that the create-drop process is happening between each test method. I am assuming that this is a time-consuming process and as such want this to only happen once before executing the tests in the application. I have attempted to do so by moving the logic into a configuration class but I get all sorts of errors using that approach.

Could someone please outline how I could achieve this?

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = App.class)
@WebIntegrationTest
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)

public abstract class AbstractDBUnitTest {

    @PersistenceUnit
    protected EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        //Set up datasource, connection etc..
        entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {

        //Clean up records

        EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();

        if (transaction != null && transaction.isActive()) {
            if (transaction.getRollbackOnly() == true) {
                transaction.rollback();
            } else {
                transaction.commit();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I can confirm that the hbm2ddl process is creating and dropping my tables once for each test class because I see this output once for every TestCase class that I execute in the application:

```
org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
```

Comment: I am not sure that is the case. The db is surely only created when the context is loaded and not before each test method? Anyway, you don't the setUp() and tearDown() methods: let Spring handle the transactions. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testcontext-tx-enabling-transactions

Comment: I think the hbm2ddl runs once before every TestCase class..not before every method. I only setup test data before every test method and clean the data out after every method. I edited the class above because I didn't include the spring-test annotations  originally because I didn't think it was necessary. But if you look at the annotations you can see there is a @DirtiesContext annotation which instructs the test how often to reload the applicationContext...and as you can see the value is set to ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS.